# Babel 7 not transpiling vendor chunk

Tags: webpack, babeljs

Some of the modules used by other imported libraries are using const instead of var and generated vendors chunk contains const which throws error on older browsers

`SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode.`

my babel config

```
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        modules: false,
      },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-react',
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
  ],
  env: {
    production: {
      only: ['app', 'ssr'],
      plugins: [
        'react-loadable/babel',
        'lodash',
        'transform-react-remove-prop-types',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements',
      ],
    },
    test: {
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
        'dynamic-import-node',
      ],
    },
  },
```

and webpack rule

```
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: Object.assign({
        sourceType: 'unambiguous',
      }),
    },
  },
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132564/babel-not-transpiling-chunk-vendors-for-ie11-in-vue-cli-project

Comment: After trying few different approaches i decided to just switch the problematic lib to a different one.