# Babel not transpiling chunk-vendors for IE11, in Vue-CLI project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, vue-cli

I have a Vue-CLI webapp that needs to support IE11. In package.json we have set:

```
"browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8",
    "ie 11"
  ]
```

and this seems to work for the generated `app.x.js` files: they don't contain any `...` operators for instance.

However, the generated `chunk-vendors.x.js` *do* contain `...` operators, and hence fail on IE11.

Relevant parts of the package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.3.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.3",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-pug": "^1.0.7",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
  },
```

There are no relevant changes in vue.config.js, so the default behaviour is being used.

What do I need to change to ensure `chunk-vendors.x.js` is transpiled for IE11?

Comment: You have some dependencies in `node_modules` using the spread operator. Find out which ones, then use the vue-cli `transpileDependecies` option. https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#transpiledependencies

Comment: Doh, didn't see this comment till just now. Yes, correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer seems to be, not so much "make sure all dependencies are transpiled" (which apparently can cause a lot of problems), but "make sure the specific dependencies which are causing issues are transpiled".

You can do this by adding a line to `vue.config.js`:

> `transpileDependencies: ['/node_modules/myproblematicmodule/']`

Comment: Any hints on identifying which modules are causing problems?

Comment: Hmm, in my case, I think it was obvious because there was a particular error message - but I don't remember much more than that.

Comment: For Vuetify I needed to simply put 'vuetify' instead of '/node_modules/vuetify/' from https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#ie-11-safari-9-support

module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify']
}

Comment: @SteveBennett how to understand which dependency needs to be transpiled?

Comment: This makes no difference for me. I can see that the issue is in "vue-masonry" and I have tried both '/node_modules/vue-masonry/' or 'vue-masonry' in transpileDependencies and it makes no difference.  I have also tried importing 'core-js/stable' and 'regenerator-runtime/runtime' in my main.js as other posts say to but still i get the same errir

Comment: It is important to note that you have to use 'babel.config.js' for 'transpileDependencies' to work!
See this issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1411

Comment: It didn't work for me. Here, you can check out my problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66984414/babel-doesnt-transpile-es6-to-es5-in-production-mode

Comment: You can know which dependency needs to be transpiled by this amazing package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/are-you-es5

Comment: in addition, you may have to change  `useBuiltIns: 'usage'` to  `useBuiltIns: 'entry'`, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58919016/babel-and-webpack-are-throwing-cant-resolve-regenerator-runtime-runtime/70095630#70095630