# Babel and Webpack are throwing "Can't resolve 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'"

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm working on a browser-based project that needs to be IE11-compatible (sigh). Webpack is choking on `async/await`. Here is my console's output:

```
Based on your code and targets, added regenerator-runtime.
...
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
```

I've looked at **many** SO questions similar to mine, without luck. Many recommend using `@babel/polyfill` which I am avoiding since it has been deprecated.

What is causing this issue? I expect it could be fixed by manually importing `regenerator-runtime/runtime`, but it seems one of the main selling points of `babel-env` is NOT having to manually import polyfills, so I assume I'm missing a step. Thank you!

**Here is what I am attempting to run,** which is being imported into another file:

```
class Fetcher {
    constructor() {
        this.form = document.querySelector('form');
        this.form.addEventListener('submit', this.onSubmit.bind(this));
    }

    async onSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const apiResponse = await fetch(`${WP_url}/api`);
        const apiJson = await apiResponse.json();
        console.log(apiJson);
    }
}
export default Fetcher;
```

**webpack.config.js**:

```
const path = require('path');

function pathTo(filepath) {
    return path.join(__dirname, filepath);
}

module.exports = function(env, argv) {
    const isProd = Boolean(argv.mode === 'production');

    const config = {
        entry: {
            index: [
                pathTo('index.js'),
            ],
        },
        externals: {
            jquery: 'jQuery',
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            [
                                '@babel/preset-env',
                                {
                                    corejs: 3,
                                    debug: true,
                                    targets: {
                                        browsers: [
                                            'IE 11',
                                        ],
                                    },
                                    useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                                },
                            ],
                        ],
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
        optimization: {
            minimize: isProd,
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            path: pathTo('web'),
        },
    };

    return config;
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.4.1",
    "focus-within-polyfill": "^5.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode=development --display-modules",
    "dev:watch": "npm run dev -- --watch",
    "prod": "webpack --mode=production --display-modules",
    "prod:watch": "npm run prod -- --watch"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply running `npm i regenerator-runtime` fixed it, actually.

With `useBuiltIns: 'usage'`, having all the `import` statements wasn't necessary I guess.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

Just add `import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'` in the file where you have the async/await.

Comment: As I said in my post, I expect it could be fixed by manually importing regenerator-runtime/runtime, but it seems one of the main selling points of babel-env is NOT having to manually import polyfills, so I assume I'm missing a step.

Comment: Yes, I expected the same when I faced the issue. Turns out it was caused when some other packages that required it, and I was only able to solve it by adding the import manually (even when it worked properly when I wasn't using those packages). Does it throw the error when manually importing it?

Comment: Just doing `npm i regenerator-runtime` fixed it, actually. With `useBuiltIns: 'usage'` having all the `import` statements wasn't necessary I guess. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Nice! I'll try that as well to reduce the need to keep track of casual `imports`.

Comment: @RobertAKARobin could you make that a separate answer? It just fixed a similar issue for me and I think not everybody scans all the comments for possible alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59324875/7149182) wasn't enough and I needed to set babel [sourceType](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#sourcetype) to `unambiguous` as suggested [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9937#issuecomment-489352549) to allow a correct compilation of the project. This option was required because the `@babel/runtime/regenerator/index.js` file exports its reference using `module.exports = require("regenerator-runtime");` that breaks ES6 compilation.

Another useful note resolving a similar but unrelated compilation issue was to use `/node_modules\/(css-loader|@babel|core-js|promise-polyfill|webpack|html-webpack-plugin|whatwg-fetch)\//` as `exclude` for the babel rule to avoid resolution loops without loosing external libraries compilation (when necessary) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58517865/7149182).

###### TL;DR

In your specific case the babel rule would become:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: {
    sourceType: 'unambiguous',
    presets: [
      ['babel/preset-env', {
        corejs: 3,
        debug: true,
        targets: {
          browsers: [ 'IE 11', ],
        },
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
      }],
    ],
  },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I started getting this error when added   `transpileDependencies: ['openplayerjs'],` to my `vue.config.js`, as Babel with `@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset` won't touch dependencies in `node_modules`, go figure why. Installing `regenerator-runtime` did not help, and I thought the issue lied in Yarn's pnp modules:

```
This dependency was not found:

* regenerator-runtime/runtime.js in /Volumes/Backup/home/Documents/.yarn/unplugged/openplayerjs-npm-2.9.3-aa4692035d/node_modules/openplayerjs/dist/esm/media.js, /Volumes/Backup/home/Documents/.yarn/unplugged/openplayerjs-npm-2.9.3-aa4692035d/node_modules/openplayerjs/dist/esm/media/ads.js and 1 other

To install it, you can run: npm install --save regenerator-runtime/runtime.js
```

so I tried unplugging everything via `yarn unplug <module_name>`, still did not work.

Eventually changing `useBuiltIns: 'usage'` to  `useBuiltIns: 'entry'` in `babel.config.js` solved it straight away.

Answer (score -2):

Following the official [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime):

1. Install required packages.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-runtime
npm install --save @babel/runtime
```

2. Add plugin to the configuration file.

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
}
```

This is officially recommended method, more available in the mentioned [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime).

Comment: `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` and `@babel/runtime` are different packages than the one OP is talking about. `regenerator/runtime` is one of the two packages that `@babel/polyfill` was importing and the docs can be found here: https://github.com/facebook/regenerator/tree/master/packages/regenerator-runtime